# Observable Markov Model: Expected number of observations

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a question that asks me "What is the expected number of observations in a state?" with the note:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{d=1}d a^{d=1} = \frac{1}{(a-1)^2}\text{ when } |a| < 1$$
Prior to that I have a Markov Model with 3 states and the transition probabilities as follows:

- S1: $P(S1) = 0.4$, $P(S2|S1) = 0.3$, $P(S3|S1) = 0.3$
- S2: $P(S2) = 0.6$, $P(S1|S2) = 0.2$, $P(S3|S2) = 0.2$
- S3: $P(S3) = 0.8$, $P(S1|S3) = 0.1$, $P(S2|S3) = 0.1$

Any guidance on what the note means or what I am trying to work out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note probably refers to the calculation of the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of a random variable $T_{i}$ that describes the time "we stay" in the state $S_i$.

From how I understand the question, this is exactly what you are tasked to compute. Therefore I understood the question as: "given that you are in some state $S_i$, how many observations of $S_i$ do you expect before changing a state?"

Comment: So I imagine for $S1$ you would expect $\approx 3$, $S2 \approx 6$ and $S3 \approx 25$?

Comment: I think you are correct, assuming this really is the intention of the question